# "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'lista' before initialization" en función Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucles, while, function, funcion

En este código intento que el usuario cargue productos a través de un prompt y hasta que ingrese ESC y la condición ya no se cumpla, el ciclo de carga de productos finalice.

El problema es que hay un error que no logro resolver. Por consola aparece

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'lista' before initialization
```

Pero no se exactamente cuál es el bloque de código que se inicializa antes de que cargue la variable lista.

¿Estará mal planteada la lógica del algoritmo?

```
let nombreProducto = "";
let descripcion = "";
let precio = 0;

let validar = prompt('Ingrese cualquier tecla para cargar \n el producto o ESC para salir');

function producto (nombreProducto, descripcion, precio) {
    nombreProducto = prompt('Ingrese el producto');
    descripcion = prompt('Ingrese breve descripción');
    precio = parseFloat(prompt('Ingrese precio sin iva'));
    let lista = lista + ("Producto : " + nombreProducto + " Descripción : " + descripcion + " Precio : " + precio);
    return lista ;
}
 while (validar != 'ESC') {
     producto();

    if ((nombre != "" ) && (descripcion != "") && (precio != "")){
        alert("Producto : " + nombreProducto + " Descripción : " + descripcion + " Precio : " + precio);
    }else{
        alert('No cargaste correctamente');
        break;
}
validar = prompt('Ingrese cualquier tecla para cargar \n un contacto o ESC para salir');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problema

El problema es que estas tratando de usar una variable antes de inicializarla.

Dentro de la funcion `producto` en la línea:

```javascript
let lista = lista + ("Producto : " + nombreProducto + " Descripción : " + descripcion + " Precio : " + precio);
```

Si leemos el error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'lista' before initialization
```

Es un error de referencia, es decir, javascript no encuentra la variable `lista` ya que la estás declarando y tratando de utilizar al mismo tiempo.

---

Para simplificar el error veamos el siguiente código:

```js
let variable1 = variable1 + "texto cualquiera";
```

Si ejecutas el bloque de arriba, podras ver que en consola se imprime el mismo error.

El error explica muy bien cuál es el problema, y es que estamos tratando de asignar a la nueva variable `variable1` el valor de `variable1` siendo que a su vez estamos declarando `variable1`.

---

### Solución

Para resolver esto, podríamos primero inicializar con un valor por defecto la variable, y luego asignarle algo, esto sería:

```js
let variable1 = ""; //cadena vacía por defecto

variable1 = variable1 + "(algun texto)";
console.log(variable1);

variable1 = variable1 + " (algun otro texto)";
console.log(variable1);
```

De esta manera no tendremos un error de referencia, ya que `variable1` ya fue declarada en la primera linea, y podemos referenciarla en las líneas siguientes.

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo @AndresGardiol... ahora bien, ya logré eliminar lista que se sumaba a producto, etc y también en el if sustituí nombre por nombreProducto ya que daba error pero el problema es que no logro hacer andar el algoritmo de buena manera ya que entra de una vez al else...  creo que lo que no logro es plantearme el ciclo debidamente para que el usuario vaya ingresando productos hasta que ingrese ESC... ya sea dejando solo el while y eliminando el for o no sé cómo...

Comment: Ese ya es un problema a parte, que quizas amerite crear una nueva pregunta. Sin embargo noto que estás comparando `validar != 'ESC'` siendo que cuando presionas la tecla escape, el valor que devuelve la funcion `prompt` es `null` y no la cadena "ESC". Por lo tanto la condición del while podría ser `while (!validar) `

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas intentando usar la variable lista que no ha sido definida. Aqui te dejo tu codigo funcionando, aunque ya para guardar lo que el usuario va dijitando deberias usar un array.

```
    let nombreProducto = "";
    let descripcion = "";
    let precio = 0;

    let validar = prompt('Ingrese cualquier tecla para cargar \n el producto o ESC para salir');

    var lista = '';

    while (validar != 'ESC') {

        function producto (nombreProducto, descripcion, precio){
            var nombreProducto = prompt('Ingrese el producto');
            var descripcion = prompt('Ingrese breve descripción');
            var precio = parseFloat(prompt('Ingrese precio sin iva'));
            let lista = "Producto : " + nombreProducto + " Descripción : " + descripcion + " Precio : " + precio;
            console.log(lista)
            if (nombreProducto != "" && descripcion != "" && precio != ""){
                alert("Producto : " + nombreProducto + " Descripción : " + descripcion + " Precio : " + precio);
            }else{
                alert('No cargaste correctamente');
            }
            validar = prompt('Ingrese cualquier tecla para cargar \n un contacto o ESC para salir');
            return lista;

        }
        producto();
        break;
    }
```